# More eclipse insanity - Cannot set Android SDK. Does not Save

Tags: android, eclipse

This is nth time that I have opened a new project, and attempted to set the Android SDK.  I select properties --> Android ---> [] Android 4.03
Click apply
Click Ok

Return and its unselected. + bunch of can't find Activity errors.  Whats up with this.  Tried project -fix properties , clean etc.

Comment: Try making the change, then closing and reopening Eclipse. I have run into this before, where the change is made to `project.properties`, but somehow Eclipse itself forgets about the change. Restarting Eclipse causes it to read `project.properties` again as part of re-establishing the workspace.

Comment: Yeah that works.  After refreshing project.properties it disappeared because of the file date or something.  Had to update it outside eclipse and than restart.